# Icono de aplicación en segundo plano con Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Tengo una aplicación básica la cual recibe mensajes desde la consola de Firebase, mi código es el siguiente:

```
private void mostrarNotificacion(String title, String body) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.escudosinfondo)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                    getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(soundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());

}
}
```

Me funciona bien, el detalle es que cuando estoy dentro de la aplicación, me muestra el mensaje y el icono que he definido, es decir:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando la aplicación esta cerrada o en segundo plano, me muestra el mensaje bien pero no el icono:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay alguna forma de solucionar esto usando la consola de Firebase? caso contrario cual sería la solución mas óptima?.

Gracias de antemano!.

Comment: Podrías agregar una imagen de lo que comentas?

Comment: Listo, ya lo edité

Comment: Ok ya veo, esto no tiene que ver con firebase, estas seguro de solo tener el mètodo mostrarNotificacion() para crear notificaciones en tu aplicación?

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que cuando la app está cerrada o en segundo plano Firebase genera una notificación por defecto con una versión "aplanada" del icono según las buenas prácticas en la últimas versiones de Android. El problema es que el icono que está utilizando no tiene transparencias y por eso sale como un cuando solido.
Para personalizar esto puede definir la siguiente metadata en el manifest de tu app para definir el icono y el color de fondo respectivamente.

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_ic_notification" />

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
    android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
```